# Sum of Absolutes

Tags: java

I was trying to solve the simple problem posted on HackerRank.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/w16/challenges/sum-of-absolutes

I solved the problem, however its getting time out error to those with input array of size 100000.  Could someone help me optimize this code below so it does not timeout.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print outputto       STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n= in.nextInt();
    int q = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    int[] a = new int[n+1];
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
          a[i]= in.nextInt();
    }
    for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
          int l = in.nextInt();
        int r = in.nextInt();
        int sum=0;
        for(int k=l;k<=r ;k++)
            {
               sum = Math.abs(sum+a[k]);
        }
        if(sum%2 == 0)
            System.out.println("Even");
        else
            System.out.println("Odd");
    }

}
```

Comment: There's no way for this code to time out

Comment: @ControlAltDel I think hackerrank runs it and times the result for you.

Comment: No dude,out of 9 test cases, 2 test cases are failing(which has input size 100000), error "Terminated due to timeout" the below is the test case input link           https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/9066/input09.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJAMR4KJHHUS76CYQ&Expires=1438879924&Signature=sWjeospwMyUOAgdCmo9U3pVmt8g%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Comment: Like I said, Hackerrank is running your code and timing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to completely rethink your solution: You don;t actually need to work out the summation in order to establish if the result is odd or even.

The observation that adding two even numbers or two odd number gives you an even; and that adding an even and an odd give you an odd for all numbers (positive and negative) should be all you need.

Comment: I tried the way u suggested, but still not able to pass those 2 test cases having 100000 array input size.

Answer (score 1):

Think about whether there's a shortcut that will give you the same odd/even answer. For example, -8 and 8 are both even while -3 and 3 are both odd. Do you really need to take an absolute value to determine if the sum is even or odd?

---Edit: Another thought or two---

First thought.
Please take a look at [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html). There are bitwise ways to figure out if the number is negative (namely: The high-order bit is 1). And there are bitwise ways to tell if the number is odd (namely: The low-order bit of a positive number is 1 and the low order bit of a negative number is 0).

--- Edit: Second thought---

Could you compress the array by not storing the input numbers, but instead the parity of those numbers? For example, you could use `boolean[] isOdd` or `BitSet isOdd`? You could store -7 in position i as `isOdd[i] = true;` or `isOdd.set(i);`. (Since BitSet and boolean both initialize to all false, you would not change the boolean or BitSet in position j if position j were even; see [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).) Then your answer would consist of counting the odds (or flipping a boolean or not'ing a bit) in the requested set and answering odd if the sum were odd (or false or 0) or even if the sum were even (or true or 1).

Why should you use a BitSet or boolean array? You can pack more information into less memory, making it easier for Java to find the space and leading to fewer page faults should you go over a page boundary.

Comment: About your "second thought" He has to go through the input numbers Q times (where Q is the number of test cases (pair of L and R).    Re-reading the file would be ridiculously slow.   What would you suggest as an alternative to keeping the values as an array?

Comment: Good question, @CPerkins. I am suggesting not keeping an array at all and accumulating the even / odd boolean on-the-fly. You do not need to keep the numbers in an array in order to arrive with the correct output. For a very long list (i.e., the ones that timed out), the OP would need to 1) allocate a large array (costly); 2) do a lot of indexing; and 3) cross memory pages. It would be simpler and faster to store the read-in number in a single int and accumulate the results of the bit twiddling.

Comment: I don't see how.  He has to go through that array(list, whatever you want to call it) of values  100,000 times.    Do you propose that he re-read the file each time?

Comment: OK, I see your point, CPerkins. The array is necessary. I will change the edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you two hints.  First, always look for needlessly repeated operations (spoiler: how many times do you do Math.abs on each value in the set?).  And second, file IO is very expensive.  Look for a way to use Scanner more efficiently.